# Using modifiers in Foundry `test`

Tags: solidity, testing, test, foundry

Is it a good practice to create `modifier`s in Foundry `test`s?

When testing cases, that share significant number of steps, but not that much that you want to create a separate testContract for them, with its own `setUp()`. (A simplistic situation could be testing a token contract where `test`s `approve` steps for testing `allowance`, `transfer` and other cases.)

I couldn't see any use of `modifier`s in examples linked by Foundry, so it raised this question: is it "safe" (in broad sense), is it a good practice at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is safe to use modifiers in tests, but I cannot speak to whether it is good practice or not. It definitely does not seem to be *common* practice.

The main reason we have not used modifiers in example code is that it might seem a little opaque for example code, not because it won't work :)